# How to draw a dotted line dynamically using OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android. I am trying to draw a dashed line in OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android programmatically. I found more ways for OpenGL ES 1.0 only.

Can anyone give me a suggestion or any OpenGL ES 2.0 sample code for Android?

Comment: harikrishnan : Are you able to achieve this using shaders?

Comment: yes. using shaders language..

Comment: can you show me the example..I have commented my problem in below answer by John.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: just refer this. it may useful to you..               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275802/in-opengl-es-2-0-android-is-it-possible-to-draw-line-circle-in-a-custom-size/16519900#16519900

Comment: Thanks..Does this code refer to dotted lines??

Comment: Harikrishnan : Thanks for the code, but I am getting blank screen. :-(

Comment: you did not use my code properly..i will give some other..

Comment: I did bro, but I get no error and it displays blank screen.

Comment: I am able to create a straight line but not dotted lines.

Comment: i will give the solution for you to my blogger and give that link to you at evening time onwards..

Comment: Waiting for your reply bro..

Comment: @harikrishnan..can you share your code for dotted lines?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution. I use it for horizontal and vertical lines.

```
#define DOT_VERTEX_CODE \
  "attribute vec4 a_Position;" \
  "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;" \
  "varying vec2 v_xy;" \
  "void main() {gl_PointSize = 1.0; gl_Position = a_Position*projectionMatrix; v_xy = a_Position.xy;}"

#define DOT_FRAGMENT_CODE \
  "precision mediump float;" \
  "varying vec2 v_xy;" \
  "uniform float isVert;" \
  "uniform vec4 color1;" \
  "uniform vec4 color2;" \
  "void main() {gl_FragColor = mod(isVert > 0.0 ? v_xy.y : v_xy.x, 2.0) >= 1.0 ? color1 : color2;}"
```